# yield is not showing nothing

Tags: laravel

Im with some doubts about how to strucure the views folder on laravel. For example a blog site where we have this structure in the homepage:

Header (where we have a menu with: a link to homepage, search bar to search for posts, sign in and login buttons)

Then a section with the last 5 posts.

Then a section with the most viewed posts.

And then a footer.

How we can structure this homepage in terms of views?  For example maybe we can something like this:

```
-views

  - layouts
    - header.blade.php
    - footer.blade.php
  - posts
     - lastposts.blade.php
     - mostviewed.blade.php
     - single.blade.php
  - layout.blade.php
```

Do you think its ok? Because Im testing this and it is not working. For example in the layout.blade.php I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
....
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

@include('layouts.nav')

@yield('lastposts')

@yield('mostviewed')

@include(layouts.footer')

</body>


</html>
```

And I get the header and the footer when I access the page corretly, but the both @yields dont show nothing.

In the lastposts.blade.php to show the last 5 posts I have:

```
@extends('layout')
@section('lastposts')
<div>
   <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div> 
<div>
   <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div> 
<div>
   <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div> 
<div>
   <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div> 
<div>
   <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div> 
@endsection
```

I have the same logic for the mostviewed.blade.php, but again, the @yield('mostviewed') dont show nothing.

Do you know what is not corret?

Routes file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('layout');
}
```

I have just this route because I just have the homepage for now.

Comment: add  the routes to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the wrong view. The parent view is layout, it doesn't know about mostviewed and lastposts. That's why you wrote @extends('layout'), that way when you create your content view, it will know that it has to extend stuff from layout.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('posts.mostviewed');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that way it shows the most viewed section, but  how to show also the last 5 pots section?

Comment: @JakL  well then you need to create another route to show that:  on your routes add:   Route::get('/lastposts', function () {
   return view('posts.lastposts');
}

Comment: Ok thanks again, but its ok have two routes for the same page? Because thi s 2 sections are loaded at the same request when the page is accessed.